# Need Help to Update the two multiple records at the same time with unique value

Tags: apex, map

Hi I am working on the scenario, and need some help from the community, kindly help me out for the below .

I have created a below map in my class : -

```
Private Map <Id, string> testMap =  new Map <Id, string>();
```

and i am populating the the map as below with the key and value pair,

```
for(Test_obj__c sId : listOfObject){
                testMap .put(sId.id, sId.TextField);
             }

Values in the above field as below, printed with the help of system.debug;
]|DEBUG|>>>>>>>>>Required Map as follows in batch in Execute Method== 
{a1f3M000000aSCYQUA3=TestValueA, a1f3M000000aSD7Q8M=TestValue4
}
```

Question or help needed:-- I need to query all the records as per the Key as Id and Update on particular field in the data base,
for example:- a1f3M000000aSCYQUA3--Stored as (sourcetestFiled) with this ID if i have got the 4 records then i need to update the particular field as  TestValueA in for all the 4 record and update;

Similarly for the another ID (a1f3M000000aSD7Q8M)

I have done from below approach:-

```
for(id icId : testMap .keySet()){
            for(Test_obj__c icToUpdate : [select id,TextField, textId__c from Test_obj__c Where textId__c =:icId]){
                icToUpdate.TextField= testMap.get(icId);
                listUpadte.add(icToUpdate);
            }
        }
```

Update List

I ahve done from the above approach, need some help to do it in the best possible way. thanks

Comment: What is the object name that needs to be updated? and what is particular field name? How object needs to be updated and Test_obj__c are related?

Comment: Hi I have updated the question

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. I suggest using [edit] and putting in a concrete, more detailed example of the values in several records (use a CSV-type layout to illustrate)- I'm unable to ascertain what the business problem is from your description

Comment: Apologies ;; But i have solved the issue thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purpose of your approach is not clear to me. But it can be optimized in following way to remove query inside for loop and nested for loop.

```
for(Test_obj__c icToUpdate : [select id,TextField, textId__c from Test_obj__c Where textId__c IN : testMap.keySet()]){
    icToUpdate.TextField= testMap.get(icToUpdate.textId__c);
    listUpadte.add(icToUpdate);
}
```

Comment: Hi I can have more then one value in the keyset() of my map...and i need to loop through all the values, kindly help me out for this

Comment: You can have upto 50,000 values and this query will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks functional. What I would caution against is making queries inside of a nested loop (you're liable to hit governor limits) and you can do some of this logic more efficiently. If you already have existing SObjects with Ids, *there is no need to query for the objects again*. In fact, all you need to do is update the field(s) that need updated, and write that to the database. I also don't see a reason to construct a map of your records.

```java
for(SObject obj : someObjects) {
  obj.TestValueA = 'Updated';
}

update someObjects;
```

If you do need to query for multiple records, use a `WHERE Id IN <collection>` clause in your SOQL. Example:

```sql
List<Some_Object__c> someObject = [
  SELECT Id, Field1, Field2
  FROM Some_Object__c
  WHERE Id IN :testMap.keySet()
];
```

That consumes only 1 query and can return hundreds of records which is much more efficient than querying for one record at a time.

Comment: Hi Thankyou so much but value incoming in my class for operation an be set of multiple

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. It could be helpful to include more code in your original post so I can see what you're trying accomplish.

Comment: Sure updating the question